# Create tar from the Map and convert it to bytearray without saving

Tags: java

I have a map which has file name as a `key` in `String` format and the contents as `value` in `bytearray` (byte[]).

I want to compress all the entries inside the map in a single tar file and convert the tar file into `bytearray` without saving anything to the disk.

As of now I am creating the tar file in temp directory and again reading the tar file as byteArray.

But is there any other way which we can create a tar file in memory and convert it to bytearray ?

I am using **appache commons** TarArchive Library. this is what I tried so far..

```
TarArchiveOutputStream outTar = new TarArchiveOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

        for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : fileMap.entrySet()){

            TarArchiveEntry tarArchiveEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(entry.getKey());
            tarArchiveEntry.setSize(entry.getValue().length);

            try {
                outTar.putArchiveEntry(tarArchiveEntry);
                outTar.write(entry.getValue());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            outTar.close();
            outTar.closeArchiveEntry();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: I already mentioned that I am creating a tar, saving in to disk and reading it as bytearray. so thats why you downvoted my question ?

I just need an approach to do it in the memory.. I am  reading the document of appache commons compress.

Comment: you told us you didn't show us.

Comment: That code looks good, but I the the closeArchiveEntry probably has to go inside the for loop. Or what else about this code is not working?

Comment: @kutschkem thats the issue...  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closeArchiveEntry has to go into the for loop, you have to close each Entry before you begin the next:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : fileMap.entrySet()){

            TarArchiveEntry tarArchiveEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(entry.getKey());
            tarArchiveEntry.setSize(entry.getValue().length);

            try {
                outTar.putArchiveEntry(tarArchiveEntry);
                outTar.write(entry.getValue());
                outTar.closeArchiveEntry();   ////////  <-----------

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            outTar.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```